How can I arrange products based on a custom value first, and then by price from low to high?
I aim to prioritize certain products within the product loop by displaying specific ones first, identified by a custom field called 'Is top product?' with a meta value of 1 when checked.
For instance, if I have a pool of 50 products, and I designate 5 as Is top product?, I want these 5 to appear at the forefront of my custom loop query. Subsequently, I wish to display the remaining 45 products in ascending order based on their prices.
Although My code works fine for showing the top products, but I'm struggling to get the others sorted by price.
1st version
$meta_query  = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key'     => 'is_top_product',
        'value'   => '1',
        'compare' => '=',
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'is_top_product',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
    ),
);

$woo_products_args['orderby']  = array(
    'is_top_product' => 'DESC', // Top products first
    '_price'          => 'ASC',  // Then sort by price
);

$woo_products_args['post_type']      = 'product';
$woo_products_args['posts_per_page'] = '12;
$woo_products_args['meta_query']     = $meta_query;
$woo_products_args['post_status']    = 'publish';

$woo_products   = new WP_Query( $woo_products_args );

2nd versions just like the first one, but with this added.
$woo_products_args['meta_key'] = '_price';

3rd version same as fisrt one just change in orderby
$woo_products_args['orderby']  = array(
    'meta_value_num' => 'DESC', // Top products first
    'meta_value_num' => 'price',  // Then sort by price
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num', // Meta value as numeric value
)

